# Saving my array using NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, arrays, singleton, persistence, nsuserdefaults

I am having trouble with `NSUserDefaults`.  Please bear with me as it is my first time implementing it.

The data I am trying to store to my phone is an array of objects for my `e-commerce` app's shopping cart, the same array that will load my cart's `table view` to display all the items added to the cart.

There are 2 different kinds of objects in the array that have different properties (`NSStrings` and `NSNumbers`: product name, size, price, etc.).  Someone suggested to me that perhaps there are too many properties in my array to put into the plist and that's why nothing is saving.

Here is my code.  I am using a `singleton` method and have inserted this code into my `singleton` class.

```
- (void)save
{  
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
    [userDefaults setObject:self.cartArray forKey:@"tableViewCartData"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
    NSURL *plistURL = [[self documentsDirectory]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"cartItems.plist"];
    [self.cartArray writeToURL:plistURL atomically:YES];
}

-(void)load
{
    NSURL *plistURL = [[self documentsDirectory]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"cartItems.plist"];

    self.cartArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:plistURL];
    if (self.cartArray == nil)
    {
        self.cartArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
}

-(NSURL *)documentsDirectory
{   
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *url = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask].firstObject;
    return url;
}
```

I can see in my Documents Directory that the plist gets created.  But there's nothing in there.

**Edit**

I just noticed this in my log:

> CityBicycleCompany[4239:249463] Property list invalid for format: 200
>   (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType') 2014-12-07
>   20:52:10.037 CityBicycleCompany[4239:249463] Attempt to set a
>   non-property-list object (
>       "" ) as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key tableViewCartData

I'm not sure what it means.  What's a CFType?

**Edit 2**

Here is the po of `self.cartArray` at the moment (added one object to "cart").  ChosenAccessory is the custom `object` I added to the cart.

```
<__NSArrayM 0x79788380>( <ChosenAccessory: 0x796d1f80> )
```

Comment: are you using mutable or nsarray

Comment: @NullData NSMutableArray

Comment: To save to NSUserDefaults, everything in your array has to be plist compliant and it looks like something might not be. Can you print out the contents of your cartArray and add it to the question?

Comment: @BenFlynn I just posted it.  I guess it is not taking it because I am filling an array with a custom object, right?

Comment: use nsarray it will work

Comment: @NullData So am I using the same code but [self.cartArray copy] instead?  Unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: did you initializing the array? If not then initialize it and then try

Answer (score 0):

You can not save array containing custom objects in NSUserDefaults directly, the apple doc: Preference values must be one of the standard property list object types: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. [a link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html)

a work around is to provide a coder/ decoder for your custom object.
in your Item class add:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder{

//for each attribute of your class that you need to store, (NSString, Date, NSNumber...)

    [coder encodeObject:self.recordID forKey:@"recordID"];//NSNumber
    [coder encodeObject:self.phone forKey:@"phone"];//NSString
    [coder encodeObject:self.date forKey:@"date"];//nsdate

}

- (Item*)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self == [super init]) {
        self.recordID = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"recordID"];
        self.phone = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"phone"];
        self.date =[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"date"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

in your viewController here is how to init and save you array of Items

```
-(void)initItems{

    self.itemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSUserDefaults* preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString* savedItems = @"savedItems";

    if([preferences objectForKey: savedItems] == nil)
    {
//handle

    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableArray *archiveArray = [preferences objectForKey: savedItems];
        for (NSData* itemObj in archiveArray) {
            Item *item = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: itemObj];
            [self.itemsArray addObject:item];
        }

    }

}


-(void)saveItemsArray{

    NSUserDefaults* preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString* savedItems = @"savedItems";

    NSMutableArray *archiveArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.itemsArray count]];

    for (Item* item in self.itemsArray) {
        NSData* itemObj = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:item];
        [archiveArray addObject:itemObj];

    }

    [preferences setObject:archiveArray forKey: savedItems];
    [preferences synchronize];

}
```